# Java JMenuBar is spread over the whole width of the window

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

I want to create a very simple JMenuBar with 2 clickable JMenuItems with the following code:

```
JFrame window = new JFrame();
JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open"), reload = new JMenuItem("Reload");
bar.add(open);
bar.add(reload);
window.setJMenuBar(bar);
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.pack();
window.setVisible(true);
```

However, the two Items have a huge space in between them and I have no idea where this is coming from:
[image]

I would expect the "Reload" item to be right next to the "Open" item.
This is the very first part of the code that runs (with a breakpoint immediately after), so nothing else can interfere with it.
Is there something 'obvious' I am missing?

Comment: Use JMenu("title") instead of JMenuItem("title")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The point is that I don't want to create Menus,

Well, a menu is designed to be clicked on and then display a popup with menu items.

If you want the ability to click on a button directly, then use a `JToolBar`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Toolbars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: thx, that's perfect. I just changed `JMenuBar` to `JToolBar`, `JMenuItem` to `JButton` and `window.setJMenuBar(bar);` to `window.getContentPane().add(bar, BorderLayout.NORTH);`

Answer (score 1):

You're probably getting confused between `JMenu` and `JMenuItem`. I suggest you to check [this tutorial of the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/menu.html#create), it'll help to comprehend the differences between the various objects.

To do what I understood you want to do you should use something like:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu open = new JMenu("Open"), reload = new JMenu("Reload");
    
    bar.add(open);
    bar.add(reload);
    ...
```

If i shattered and you meant to create a single `JMenu` with two `JMenuItems` you can easily do the following:

```
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu menu = new JMenu("A menu");    // creating a menu to hold the two items
    JMenuItem open = new JMenuItem("Open"), reload = new JMenuItem("Reload");
    
    menu.add(open);
    menu.add(reload);
    ...
```

Comment: The point is that I don't want to create Menus, I want to open/reload when clicking on the corresponding Menu/Item. When using the JMenu, the event won't trigger.